# gtk glade aide : Destroy Signal problems

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

After generating my simple glade that just opens a signal I want to connect it with my `.c` for the destroy signal to apply, but always get the exception

> "we could not find a signal handler" on_window_main_destroy "

can anyone figure out where the problem is?

here is my code in c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
GtkWidget *g_lbl_hello;
GtkWidget *g_lbl_count;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder;
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "windows_main.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "windows_main"));

    // get pointers to the two labels
    g_lbl_hello = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_hello"));
    g_lbl_count = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_count"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    //g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when button is clicked

void on_btn_hello_clicked()
{
    static unsigned int count = 0;
    char str_count[30] = {0};

    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_lbl_hello), "Hello, world!");
    count++;
    sprintf(str_count, "%d", count);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_lbl_count), str_count);
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

and here is my glade

[image]

Comment: Please post your glade file as text. Photos are almost worthless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using MS Windows. If that is the case, then the documentation for [gtk_builder_connect_signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals) clearly says:

> When compiling applications for Windows, you must declare signal
>   callbacks with G_MODULE_EXPORT, or they will not be put in the symbol
>   table.

Prefix your callback modules with `G_MODULE_EXPORT`:

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_btn_hello_clicked()
{
...
}

G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_window_main_destroy()
{
...
}
```

PS: You may need to add `gmodule-2.0` to the dependencies.